# php. should I create class for one static function

Tags: php

my question is about style of programming. I need to write one function, which calls other script from PHP. What is the best way to include such function into the project. Should I create class with one static method, or I should  just write it in a php file and include that file?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: I think it all depends on whether you're using Object-Oriented programming style or procedural programming style. Some would argue that OOP is the way to go, as it is more maintainable. If you're writing a small script, you can write the function and include it. It's up to you, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static in a class is a fancy way to write a function. Just write the function.